# UICollectionViewCell Not Displaying anything

Tags: ios6, uicollectionview

I have a custom CollectionViewCell

```
@interface FBPicCell : UICollectionViewCell
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *picby;
```

In my code in `viewDidLoad` I have

```
[self.fbpiccollectionView registerClass:[FBPicCell class]  forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"fbpiccell"];
```

and in `cellForItemAtIndexPath` function

```
FBPicCell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"fbpiccell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[cell.picby setText:@"Pavan"];
[cell.picby setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

But I don't see anything, just the white border. Not sure where i am messing things up. Any pointer would be helpful.

Comment: I am experiencing this behaviour as well.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem along with registring your call
register the nib as well as-

```
[collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"cellname" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellname"];
```

This worked for me
Regards

Comment: Thank you!!! this was driving me nuts. I'm on Xcode6.1 using iOS8 and registerClass does NOT work